# doing spark-shell with mlib, error: object jblas is not a member of package org

Tags: apache-spark

In spark-shell, when I exectue `import org.jblas.DoubleMatrix`, it will throw "error: object jblas is not a member of package org" on the RHEL.

Actually, I googled about "jblas" and installed "gfortran" from https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries#MacOS on my mac pro.

My spark version is spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tar or spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6.tar, which is download directly from the official website, it's to say that I didn't build from the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This step may be optional, it will install the jblas jar on your laptop repository.

```
git clone https://github.com/mikiobraun/jblas.git
cd jblas
mvn install
```

Enter into the spark directory

```
cd /Users/erichan/Garden/spark-1.5.1-bin-cdh4
```

Launch the spark shell with packages option, and if you didn't do the first step, you should give the right maven coordinate for jblas:

```
bin/spark-shell --name my_mlib --packages org.jblas:jblas:1.2.4-SNAPSHOT --driver-memory 4G --executor-memory 4G --driver-cores 2
```

Comment: You don't need to install jblas. You can get with the --packages option

Comment: Could you add some details of why this should work? Code-only answers are not very useful and are subject to deletion.

Comment: Make sure you have ruby installed before 'mvn install'